# A duplicated segue processing with UIStoryBoardSegue between two UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, segue, delegation

I have two screens. The first is based on UITableView instance. When I tap cell, function `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` triggers:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedEmg = selectedEmergencies[indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowMoreInfoAboutEmg", sender: self)
}
```

Here is storyboard:

[image: storyboard]

But in fact, the segue **"ShowMoreInfoAboutEmg"** duplicates itself and second screen.

[image]

I can cut `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` and the transition between screens will work correctly. However I need to transfer data from `UITableViewCell` instance to remote `UIViewController`'s property. Otherwise I get something like this:

[image]

`prepare(for:sender:)` starts to work earlier than `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` and remote view controller gets nil object from cell. Any tips, guys?

### The decision is found.

The simple and useful UITableView's property `indexPathForSelectedRow`.

I didn't touch my storyboard but I removed `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` implementation completely and just have added one line. It's enough to use `prepare(for:sender:)` totally. The general implementation is something like below:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "SomeCustomIdentifier" {
            guard let remoteViewController = segue.destination as? CustomViewController else {
                fatalError("CustomViewController instance is not found ")
            }
            selectedItem = items[(self.customTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]
            remoteViewController.selectedItemFromTable = selectedItem
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be much simpler:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedEmg = selectedEmergencies[indexPath.row]
    if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EmgDetailsPresenter") as? EmgDetailsPresenter {
        vc.selectedEmgFromTable = selectedEmg
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

P.S. Don't forget to remove segue in Storyboard and add `Storyboard ID` to `EmgDetailsPresenter`

Comment: Not bad. I use instantiateController(withIdentifier:) in different place of my project. But in current case the one reason can be a little trouble. And it's animation. So, transition from cell and popover style aren't equal visually. But I agree, that's simpler.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you're calling didselectrow from the code and also the segue from the cell in the story board. Delete the segue linking the cell in the Showmoreinfoaboutemg. Then create a segue from the whole showmoreinforaboutemg viewcontroller to the the one it is supposed to go to. Give it the same reuse identifier and problem solved

Edit: the issue is that you are calling the segue twice once on click in the story board and the select time on click in the code with did select row.

Comment: What an interesting decision.. I might use it later. Thanks!